# reactjs: material ui: how to fit button and text below using grid

Tags: material-ui

I have below image. I want to fit some text below the button.
how to do it.

[image]

Comment: can you share what you have until now? a codesandbox would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `Grid`. By default the max grid size is ***12***, so you can add two elements with size of ***6*** to be on one row and then add one with size of ***12*** to be on the next row.

```js
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <Button>Some Button</Button>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <p>some text beside</p>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <p> Some Information here </p>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Only change here i want is, instead of xs={6} can we stick to the size of the button. and i want the below information to follow the same size as the button above

Comment: If you pass `fullWidth` property inside the button like `<Button fullWidth>SomeButton</Button>` it will take the whole width of the container and you can easily just change the size of the grid.